# Is there a way to slowly add letters to text by css?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to display a word (suppose Slow), is there a way to first display 'slow' then by CSS animation add few O's in the middle,
making it from Slow to Sloooooow.

I am using latest chrome so any CSS3/HTML5 features are welcome.

Comment: I`m not sure but are you looking for this https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/jrWwWM type of animation ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can consider animating the maximum width of a span like below.

```css
.slow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: slow 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slow {
  from {
    max-width: 0.5rem;
  }
  to {
    max-width: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Sl</span><span class="slow">oooooo</span><span>w</span>
```

Comment: Am I the only one seeing just half an `o` once the animation is done? Safari 12/ MacOS Mojave... - Jup it works fine on Chrome but for some weird reason not on safari....

Comment: @somethinghere It gets even weirder: on iOS (latest) the first time I ran the snippet it worked fine, but after that each time I pressed the “run snippet” button only half an o came into view.

Comment: That's because `3rem` is the wrong way to calculate the width of the text. The actual width depends on the font. On my machine, Chrome uses Times New Roman and works fine, but Firefox uses Liberation Sans, which fails.

Comment: @isanae I don't think that is it - safari uses Times New Roman, and the `3rem` actually refers to the `:root` size, which is (when not modified) something like 16 pixels (`rem` has nothing to do with the sizes in the font, its just relative to a pixel size defined either at the root (`rem`) or at the first parent that defines it (`em`)). Don't get me wrong, this might be it, but it's still strange.

Comment: @somethinghere Font size can be set in browser preferences. If it's 16px in `<html>`, then `3rem` means 3*16, which is 48 pixels. Six `o`'s in Times 16px is indeed exactly 48 pixels, which I guess is why it's used here, since Times is often the default font where none is specified (and stack snippets iframes have basically no css). If your font is not Times, then the width might be wrong. Liberation at 16px, for example, needs 54 pixels for six `o`'s.

Comment: @isanae yeah okay, in that regard font does make a difference. But i’m seeing half of one O, definitely no more than 8px. :)

Comment: @11684 same on safari OSX 10.13

Answer (score 35):

You could add all the additional `o`s as `<span>` elements and then animate them all consecutively using `:nth-child` to select them one by one:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 10vw;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 span {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
@keyframes in {
  from { max-width: 0; opacity: 0; }
  25% { max-width: 1em; opacity: 0; }
  to { max-width: 1em; opacity: 1; }
}
h1 span {
  animation: in 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
h1 span:nth-child(1){ animation-delay: 0s; }
h1 span:nth-child(2){ animation-delay: 1s; }
h1 span:nth-child(3){ animation-delay: 2s; }
h1 span:nth-child(4){ animation-delay: 3s; }
h1 span:nth-child(5){ animation-delay: 4s; }
h1 span:nth-child(6){ animation-delay: 5s; }
h1 span:nth-child(7){ animation-delay: 6s; }
h1 span:nth-child(8){ animation-delay: 7s; }
h1 span:nth-child(9){ animation-delay: 8s; }
```

```html
<h1>Slo<span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>o</span>w</h1>
```

Comment: on Windows, Firefox the additional "o" are offset to the top, with their top at the top end of the S and l and their baseline roughly at the center of the first o.

Comment: @tom Gotta give it to Firefox, where `inline-block` means 'lets not align this to the line'; nothing that `vertical-align: bottom` doesn't fix but why FF needs to act special, god knows.

Comment: now it shows properly.

Answer (score 27):

Just for fun, here's a solution in actual pure CSS (i.e. only requiring a single HTML element), using the `content` CSS property:

```css
.expanding-slow::before {
  content: "Slo";
  animation: expand-slow linear 3s both;
}
.expanding-slow::after { content: "w"; }
@keyframes expand-slow {
  0% { content: "Slo"; }
  20% { content: "Sloo"; }
  40% { content: "Slooo"; }
  60% { content: "Sloooo"; }
  80% { content: "Slooooo"; }
  100% { content: "Sloooooo"; }
}

.expanding-slow--smooth::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Sloooooo";
  max-width: 3ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  animation: expand-slow--smooth linear 3s both;
}
.expanding-slow--smooth::after { content: "w"; }
@keyframes expand-slow--smooth {
  0% { max-width: 3ch; }
  100% { max-width: 8ch; }
}
```

```html
Using <code>content</code>:
<p class="expanding-slow"></p>

Using <code>max-width</code>:
<p class="expanding-slow--smooth"></p>
```

Comment: Using `content` does not work in Safari 12/MacOS Mojave. The `max-width` one does and its clever.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a revised version of @DarioSanchezMartinez 's answer that fits a bit closer to your spec.

```css
/* Taken from http://animista.net/play/entrances/fade-in */


#animate-1 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          
}

#animate-2 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}

#animate-3 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}

#animate-4 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
SL<span id="animate-1">o</span><span id="animate-2">o</span><span id="animate-3">o</span><span id="animate-4">o</span>W
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes!

```css
/* Taken from http://animista.net/play/entrances/fade-in */


#animate-1 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          
}

#animate-2 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}

#animate-3 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 2s;
}

#animate-4 {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
         animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
          animation-delay: 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="animate-1">S</h1>
<h1 id="animate-2">L</h1>
<h1 id="animate-3">O</h1>
<h1 id="animate-4">W</h1>
```

Comment: this just prints the letter one by one. not what I'm looking for

Comment: This answer could be fixed: Just change all characters to "o", write `sl` and `w` around it, and change H1 to SPAN's.